# What's Causing an Error in My Dropbox Access Token Retrieval Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I'm trying to create a script to get a data file from Dropbox. I'm using the code below to obtain a Dropbox access token, but it's not working and gives me an error. What could be the issue?

```
function createDropboxOAuth2Service() {
  return OAuth.createService('Dropbox')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize')
    .setTokenUrl('https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId(DROPBOX_APP_KEY)
    .setClientSecret(DROPBOX_APP_SECRET)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setScope('files.content.read');
}
```

It's not working and always shows an error.

[image]

Comment: From your showing script and image, I thought that in this case, a Google Apps Script library ( https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2 ) is required to be installed. But, in your image, it seems that the library is not installed. So, how about installing it? In that case, the identification of the library might be automatically set as `OAuth2`. Please be careful about this. But, I'm not sure whether your client ID and secret are valid 
 values for using the API. So, in the current stage, I proposed it as a comment.

Comment: Adding up to Tanaike's comment, here you can check how to add a library to your App Script project: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project